# Cmake ExternalProject Installer

Tags: cmake, external-project

I have an external project where the windows distribution is an .exe installer rather than a tarball. I could run the .exe from the command line, but cmake of course complains that it can't find a tarball filename in the URL. Is there some way to use ExternalProject with .exe installers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/ExternalProject.html) for the  `URL` parameter indicates that the URL passed must represent a tarball containing the source:

> The URL option may refer locally to a directory or source tarball, or refer to a remote tarball (e.g. http://.../src.tgz).

This is in line with the fact that `ExternalProject`'s purpose is centered in large part around *building things from source*, not just installing them.

What you'll likely want to do is set `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND` to a commandline invocation that will download the .exe. `DOWNLOAD_COMMAND` is a lower-level thing, you can basically make it do whatever you want.

Comment: And for anyone else interested, in order to issue a cross-platform download command, I used file(GENERATE ...) to write a cmake script that does file(DOWNLOAD ...). So in ExternalProject, my DOWNLOAD_COMMAND invokes cmake -P <the-generated-cmake-script-that-downloads>